# Addin Word : Is there an alternative to the Shape object that Microsoft can offer for VB but using the Office Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, office-js, word-addins

I'm creating a Word addin using Office-JS and I would like to draw on my word document using the Word API. According to my research, the closest thing would be Shape objects but it seems that this is not yet implemented in the Word API 1.3. So I'm looking for information to know if there is an alternative ?

This is the result I am looking for:
[image]

Thank you in advance !